# How can I send log4j logs to an arbitrary program listening on a socket

Tags: log4j, flume, flume-ng

I am using `log4j 1.2`

How can I send log4j logs to an arbitrary program listening on a socket. I tried following options

1. `SocketAppender` -  it expects a `SocketNode` to listen on the port.
2. `TelnetAppender` but it sends logs to a read-only port.

What I am really looking for is to send `log4j` logs to `Flume`. I know that `log4j2.X` has a `FlumeAppender` but not sure if it works with `log4j1.2`

Answer (score 0):

If Flume runs in the same machine where log4j logs are being stored, then there is no need to send the logs to Flume, but configure Flume to directly read those logs. Regarding that, please try to configure the [`Exec`](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source) source with a `tail` command execution. `tail` will *print* the logs line by line (I guess Flume somehow redirects the stdout to a internal file descriptor or something like that) and Flume will get those lines as input data.

Answer (score 0):

I found `org.apache.flume.clients.log4jappender.Log4jAppender` using Avro
to send logs to flume agent running locally on the machine